# Função da tecla Insert - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

No *VS Code*, alguém sabe como configura para fazer a tecla *"Insert"* alterar a função, para em vez de inserir os caracteres digitados passar a substituir. Como funciona no *CMD* e em alguns editores de texto?

Comment: eu não sei se isso te ajuda mas, você poderia instalar a extensão Vim no seu VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não existe por padrão no VS Code. Não sei o motivo, já que é algo extremamente comum. Você pode ver sobre isto [nesta *issue* no GitHub do VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1012).

Uma das coisas que podem ser feitas é instalar [a extensão Overtype](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype). Usando ela a função de sobrescrever será ativada/inativada ao pressionar a tecla <kbd>Insert</kbd>, como normalmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! Ajudou muito!